# In Spring Security, how can I use both session and stateless authentication in one server?

Tags: spring, security, session, stateless

In Spring Security, how can I use session for some url(eg. /index.html), and meanwhile use stateless for other url(eg. /api/view) in one server?  I only see the session can be disabled globaly, but I want to disable by url, how can I do this? Thank you.

By the way, I'm using Spring Security 4.0 with Spring Boot and like to use java configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple http elements with different create-session attributes in each. See [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points) and [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session)